# Socket permission denied when running cardano node as linux service

Tags: cardano-node

I've successfully setup and running cardano node from terminal. Now I've setup cardano node to run as service(systemd, Ubuntu) so that I don't have to run the command all the time and have a terminal always open. From journalctl log all looks good, and I have check tip is reached using explorer.cardano.org. However, I now get error when using cardano-cli and I cannot figure out why...

**Details**

*Cardano-cli error message*

Network.Socket.connect: <socket: 11>: permission denied (Permission denied)

*ls command*

- srwxr-xr-x 1 root root      0 juni  26 23:45 node.socket=

*.service file*

[Unit]
Description=Runs cardano-node mainnet
After=network-online.target
StartLimitIntervalSec=0

[Service]
Type=simple
Restart=always
RuntimeMaxSec=432000
User=root
ExecStart=/home/toby/cardano-scripts/run-cnode-main.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

*run-cnode-main.sh*

#!/bin/bash
#Start cardano-node on mainnet
/home/toby/.local/bin/cardano-node run --config /home/toby/cardano-main/mainnet-config.json --database-path /home/toby/cardano-main/db/ --socket-path /home/toby/cardano-main/db/node.socket --host-addr 127.0.0.1 --port 1337 --topology /home/toby/cardano-main/mainnet-topology.json

Answer (score 1):

1. Stop using root (for interactive as well as systemd startup user), it's a terrible idea to run applications
2. You cannot (*should not) run something as another user and point to paths in your own $HOME folder, this will more often than not only lead you to permission errors.
3. I assume `node.socket=` was a typo, if not - your start command does not match $CARDANO_NODE_SOCKET_PATH environment variable.

While you can now address the state by recursively fixing permissions, you've likely populated environment variables, build caches, profiles, etc across a mix of `root` and `toby` user, you might want to start from scratch and not run anything to do with cardano-node.

Comment: 0. Thanks for the reply! 

1. Okay, I am no linux expert:) I just followed some tutorial online, however I saw that there were some cardano tutorials that created an own user for cardano node. I will look into that.

2. Noted.

3. This was actually not a typo. I found this a bit weird, because I could not recall the socket filename had an = when running command line directly. However, now I don't understand why I do not get a "cannot find socket" error instead... My $CARDANO_NODE_SOCKET_PATH points to a file without the =

Comment: If there are online tutorials using root, I think it's potentially good to highlight bad practices to them (if they've a way to contact on their pages).

About 3, if it wasnt a typo, then perhaps one of your earlier attempts to run `cardano-node` may have accidentally had an `=` sign after socket. Once you stop all instances of node running, you should be alright

Comment: Okay, I will try to delete the db folder and have a new go for scratch. Thanks for the input @RdLrT!